# Java System.arraycopy array bounds

Tags: java, arrays, audio, byte

I'm trying to stream audio through a buffer with the size of 65536 bytes.

What will happen if I copy the a piece of my audio data to the buffer by [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) and the remaining Audio data is smaller than 65536? Will it throw an error or will it copy the remaining bytes to the buffer without any errors?

That's my code for now:

```
int offset = 0;
while(isAudioActive)
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    System.arraycopy(this.currentFile.getSampledata().getData(), 65536 * offset, buffer, 65536 * offset, 65536);

            //<<writing Audio to track here>>
    offset++;
}
```

So the System copies audio data to the buffer in little pieces.
I'm using little pieces because I want to pause/stop the music later.

Comment: did you try executing it?

Comment: Or reading the documentation?

Comment: Presumably, getData() (in your example) is giving you access to *all* of the bytes of your audio data?  If so, why do you need to buffer anything?  (BTW It would help to know what `currentFile` is.)

Comment: Could you make use of [AudioInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html)?

Comment: Paul, im Splitting it into pieces because i want to pause/stop/Play it dynamically.

Comment: Oh btw. im working with Android SDK ***

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the code will not work and throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Please check the positions in your target array `buffer`.

In the first iteration of the while-loop offset is 0 and you are writing to positions 0 to 65535. In the second iteration you are writing to the position 65536 * offset with offset = 1.  So you are starting at `buffer[65536]` which causes the above mentioned exception.

Concerning the question for the remaining data... this should also not work: Your code always copies a fixed length of 65536 bytes from source to target array. You may reach a position in your source array with the condition srcPos+length > src.length, then you will also have an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. fixed it ^^ Need a reason for the arraycopy now.